# Did JFK Attempt to eliminate the power of the Federal Reserve Bank to loan money to the US?

Tags: united-states, economics

According to [this site](http://worldtruth.tv/):

> On June 4, 1963, a virtually unknown Presidential decree, Executive
>   Order 11110, was signed with the authority to basically strip the
>   Federal Reserve Bank of its power to loan money to the United States
>   Federal Government at interest. With the stroke of a pen, President
>   Kennedy declared that the privately owned (and thus ILLEGALLY placed
>   in control of our currency, 100 years ago) Federal Reserve Bank would
>   soon be out of business.

So did JFK sign EO 11110 on June 4, 1963 and did that order do as this site claims?

Comment: Please note that the site in question infers(or maybe even claims) that this is the reason for JFK being murdered.  That is not a claim I am attempting to challenge or even address.

Comment: So, did it put the Fed out of business? Why not?

Comment: @adam.r No, it did not put the Fed out of business, but actually [strengthened rather than weakened it](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/30572/4301).

Answer (score 23):

Yes, he signed it on June 4, 1963. The [text of the Executive Order](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=59049) can be found online:

> SECTION 1. Executive Order No. 10289 of September 19, 1951, as
>   amended, is hereby further amended --
>
> (a) By adding at the end of paragraph 1 thereof the following
>   subparagraph (j):
>
> "(j) The authority vested in the President by paragraph (b) of section
>   43 of the Act of May 12, 1933, as amended (31 U.S.C. 821 (b)), to
>   issue silver certificates against any silver bullion, silver, or
>   standard silver dollars in the Treasury not then held for redemption
>   of any outstanding silver certificates, to prescribe the denominations
>   of such silver certificates, and to coin standard silver dollars and
>   subsidiary silver currency for their redemption," and
>
> (b) By revoking subparagraphs (b) and (c) of paragraph 2 thereof.
>
> SEC. 2. The amendment made by this Order shall not affect any act
>   done, or any right accruing or accrued or any suit or proceeding had
>   or commenced in any civil or criminal cause prior to the date of this
>   Order but all such liabilities shall continue and may be enforced as
>   if said amendments had not been made.

However, I don't see anything in the text that would strip the Federal reserve of any power to loan money. Specifically, it only delegated *existing* Presidential power to the Treasury Department.

Further, Kennedy was vocal in his desire to [stop using silver](http://archive.org/stream/EconomicReportOfThePresidentJanuary1963#page/n21/mode/2up) as a monetary metal, with a plan to [replace silver certificates](http://news.google.com/newspapers?id=-q8fAAAAIBAJ&sjid=LdcEAAAAIBAJ&pg=2964,4612588) with Federal Reserve notes. That would seem to be at odds with the claim that he was trying to put the Fed out of business.

Comment: It might be useful context to summarize the sense of Order 10289 paragraph 1. Eg is it listing powers that are being waived?

Comment: @NateEldredge: Paragraph 1 consists of the "The Secretary of the Treasury is hereby designated and empowered to perform the following-described functions of the President without the approval, ratification, or other action of the President:" followed by a lettered list of specific delegations. I cannot find a convient copy of the original (unammended order online), so I have no link, but cite the order itself as evidence of its contents.